# How to act in difficult situations with dishonest people?

Tags: practical-islam, relationships

What are we suppose to do if we can't get along with someone at work or as neighbor. Suppose someone is dishonest or cheating in his dealing with another. Do you ignore him or pray for him? What does the Quran tell us about this issue? Is it eye for eye or do nothing and accept the 'suffering'?

Answer (score 4):

Allah said in the "Fossilat"(41) Chapter of Quran:

> {وَلَا تَسْتَوِي الْحَسَنَةُ وَلَا السَّيِّئَةُ ۚ ادْفَعْ بِالَّتِي هِيَ أَحْسَنُ فَإِذَا الَّذِي بَيْنَكَ وَبَيْنَهُ عَدَاوَةٌ كَأَنَّهُ وَلِيٌّ حَمِيمٌ(34)}

In this ayah, Allah tells his Prophet, Mohammad (peace be upon him), that good and evil are not equal, and tells him to repel evil with that which is good. Whenever he does so, he will see that whoever there exists an enmity between them, the other person will suddenly become as if they were his bosom friend.

So, we should learn from this ayah that we should be patient and treat people well even if they do not do so to us, and we should do this for the sake of Allah expecting mercy and forgiveness from Him.

*And Allah knows best*.